# Cylindrical/ Spherical Coordinates Integral - Volume of Cone

Tags: calculus, volume

"(b) Let $C$ be the solid cone with the boundary surfaces $x^2 +y^2 = z^2$ and $z = 0$. The density of the solid at point $(x, y,z)$ is $z$.
Find the volume of the solid using the integrals in both the cylindrical coordinates and the spherical coordinates."

I have done this question and got an answer that is $\frac{\pi}{4z}$ in cylindrical and $\frac{\pi}{8z}$ in spherical. I took $\phi$ in spherical coordinates to be between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Certainly the volume should be the same regardless of what coordinates you use.

Comment: Would the correct limits for phi be 0 and pi/4?

Comment: I don't think the question even makes sense: The two surfaces doesn't actually bound a (finite) region.

Comment: It appears to work with limits of 0 and pi/2.. ?

Comment: @JLL No, that is the start of the question, part a is unrelated...

Comment: As written, you're describing an infinite cone. Are you sure one of the boundaries is $z=0$?

Comment: Thanks everyone, the question is correct. I think maybe the intention is to take r/ rho from 0 to 1?

Comment: The question does not appear to be correct. Anyway, try drawing a triangle. If this is a cone with a flat base at some height $z=h$, you'll notice that $\rho$ changes in magnitude along it. You may have to express $\rho$ in terms of the height and a trigonometric relationship with the polar angle.

Comment: It appears the question has been asked elsewhere http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256406/finding-volume-of-a-cone-given-density would anyone please be able to explain the dV formula? Thanks @zahbaz

Comment: I have a feeling this question may be to do with a trigonometric relationship rather than a specific answer, as @zahbaz has suggested